# The function definitions in shell use dash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The following code：

```
#!/bin/bash

function me-test()
{
        echo 'test'
}

me-test
```

The execution method below is not correct：

```
#sh 1.sh
1.sh: line 6: `me-test': not a valid identifier
```

but the execution method below is correct:

```
#./1.sh
test
```

In other programming languages,it can not using dash to define function.For example,python.

why shell is so that?

Comment: Also, the `function` syntax is not standard, and may not work with all posix-compatible shells.

Comment: For anyone looking for a direct answer to the question about bash allowing a hyphen character in function names see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168221/7084.  Also regarding bash specifically, the bash manual says that "In default mode (as opposed to POSIX mode), a function name can be any unquoted shell word that does not contain `'$'`".   See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions.

Answer (score 1):

`sh 1.sh` runs the script as a [Bourne Shell](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/sh/) script and `./1.sh` runs it as a [bash](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/bash/) script because of your line `#!/bin/bash` (this is called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) which tells the shell which interpreter to use) calls the bash interpreter to run the script. bash allows for hyphens in function names but Bourne Shell does not. The two are very similar but different programming languages.

If you changed `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` you'd get an error every time you ran the program.

Comment: I know,i want to know that why "bash" can and "sh" can not

Comment: ^^ becauase they are different.

Comment: @anishsane is correct.

Comment: `sh` is almost certainly whatever shell your system uses as its POSIX-compliant shell, not the actual Bourne shell. If that shell happens to be `bash`, `bash` tries to be a little stricter in its emulation of the POSIX standard.